# Is there a way to find out what user owns a process from the process's task_struct?

Tags: multithreading, process, permissions, linux-kernel, pid

I have a `task_struct *` that I got by calling `find_task_by_vpid(get_pid())`. I'd like to figure out what user owns that process so that I can do some permission checking in the system call I'm writing, but looking through the `task_struct` source code hasn't helped much. The only thing that looked helpful is the `loginuid`, but for some reason the kernel won't compile if I try to access it like this: `my_task_struct->loginuid`. Is there another way to get the user who called the process from the `task_struct`?

Comment: Look at the implementation of `geteuid`.  For permission checks, though, you almost certainly want to use the existing general framework for that sort of thing rather than making up your own logic that is inconsistent with the rest of the system.

Comment: I use `geteuid()` to get the `euid` of the user who called the system call, but I'm not sure how to use it to get the `uid` (or `euid`) of the `task_struct` for the `pid` passed into the system call itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, the user/group ids are no longer stored in the task struct, but instead in a separate privilege structure that's dynamically allocated and shared between all tasks that have the same ids. This in turn creates a situation where `setuid` can fail due to resource exhaustion, and failure of `setuid` to prop privileges is an infamous source of vulnerabilities...

Anyway, it's in these members of the `task_struct`:

```
    const struct cred __rcu *real_cred; /* objective and real subjective task
                                     * credentials (COW) */
    const struct cred __rcu *cred;  /* effective (overridable) subjective task
                                     * credentials (COW) */
```

Comment: Thanks this really help. do you know how to initialize where initialized that user_struct?

Comment: @saman: Not right off, but go find the code for `setuid()` etc. and you should see some examples of how it's done.

Comment: @R.. I only can find the declaration of setuid system call in the  unistd.h but I can't find implementation of this system call [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27594865/add-another-field-to-user-struct) is my question can you answer it?

Answer (score 0):

To access a user ID (UID) within the kernel space you can do something along the following lines (as of Linux 4.9.13):

```
struct task_struct *task;
for_each_process(task) {
    uid_t uid = __kuid_val(task_uid(task));
}
```

`task_uid` returns a structure called `kuid_t` and to access the actual value you have to either call `__kuid_val` or access it directly (`task_uid(task).val`).

Alternatively, you can use `from_kuid(&init_user_ns, task_uid(task))`.